# Have Matt Murdock and Jennifer Walters ever appeared in court together?

Tags: marvel, daredevil, she-hulk

Matt Murdock (Daredevil) and Jennifer Walters (She-Hulk) are both lawyers in the Marvel Universe, as well as superheroes. Has there ever been a case where the two of them have appeared in court together, either as opposing sides, or working the same case?

Comment: https://www.cbr.com/comic-book-questions-answered-have-daredevil-and-she-hulk-ever-faced-each-other-in-court/2/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**

For example in the case between Jen Walters and Matt Murdock over the fate of Steve Rogers, as presented in Charles Soule and Javier Pulido’s She-Hulk 10

https://retcon-punch.com/2014/11/19/she-hulk-10/